# How I can change values on the Y-axis

Tags: pgfplots, plot, gnuplot

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-fct,tkz-base}
\usepackage{tkz-tab,tkz-euclide}
 \usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
 \usetikzlibrary{%
 decorations.pathreplacing,%
 decorations.pathmorphing%
 }

 \newlength\figureheight
 \newlength\figurewidth
 \setlength\figureheight{6cm}
 \setlength\figurewidth{6cm}
 \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.75000,0.75000}%
 \definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.75000,0.00000,0.75000}%

 \begin{document}
 \centering

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{semilogyaxis}[xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1, samples=1000, fill=blue]
  \addplot[black!50,thick ] (x,{exp(-1/2)*(1-exp((-2*x)/0.01))+(1/2)*exp(-1/2)*(1+exp((-2*x)/0.01))+(1/8)*(0.01)exp(-1/2)(1-exp((-2*x)/0.01))});
  \addplot[red,thick ] (x,{exp(-(1/2)+x/2)+((0.01)/8)*(1-x)*exp(-(1/2)+x/2)});
  \addplot[blue,thick ] (x,{-exp(-(1/2)-(2*x)/0.01)+(1/2)xexp(-(1/2)-(2*x)/0.01)+exp(-(1/2)+x/2)+(0.01/8)*(-exp(-(1/2)-(2*x)/0.01)+(1-x)*exp(-(1/2)+x/2))});
\end{semilogyaxis} 
\end{tikzpicture} %
[\epsilon=1000, \quad a_0=1,\quad \omega_0=1] %
[\text{$--$'' pertubasyon \c{c}\"{o}z\"{u}m\"{u},$-$'' n\"{u}merik \c{c}\"{o}z\"{u}m}]
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Could you make your example compilable ?

Comment: What do you want to change them to/how do you want to change them?

Comment: Dear Torbjorn, I really appreciate your concern. You are very kind and helpful because of numerious help topics you are involved. Your answer has solved my problem. thank you again.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Consider also upvoting and/or accepting useful answers. Accepting an answer marks the question as solved.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you want to keep the logarithmic scaling on the y-axis, but you can't have `ymin=0` with a logarithmic y-axis, so I changed that to `0.1`. I suppose you want something like the example below. I simply specified the `ytick`s and `yticklabels` manually. It may not be the most elegant solution, but it works at least.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
  xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0.1, ymax=1,
  samples=1000,
  fill=blue,
  ytick={0.1,0.2,...,1},
  yticklabels={0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1}
] 
\addplot[black!50,thick ] 
(x,{exp(-1/2)*(1-exp((-2*x)/0.01))+(1/2)*exp(-1/2)*(1+exp((-2*x)/0.01))+(1/8)*(0.01)*exp(-1/2)*(1-exp((-2*x)/0.01))}); 
\addplot[red,thick ] (x,{exp(-(1/2)+x/2)+((0.01)/8)*(1-x)*exp(-(1/2)+x/2)}); 
\addplot[blue,thick ] (x,{-exp(-(1/2)-(2*x)/0.01)+(1/2)*x*exp(-(1/2)-(2*x)/0.01)+exp(-(1/2)+x/2)+(0.01/8)*(-exp(-(1/2)-(2*x)/0.01)+(1-x)*exp(-(1/2)+x/2))}); 
\end{semilogyaxis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]